# Start menu still uses Edge

Tags: windows-10, firefox, start-menu, microsoft-edge

I have Windows 10, and have grown used to pressing the windows key and typing a quick search. Usually it would use Firefox, my default browser. However, after I reinstalled Windows, it keeps trying to use edge. I have changed the default programs in settings and control panel, resetting to microsoft defaults and trying again, I have tried using chrome, and i have tried disabling edge, all to no avail. Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: [Here](http://www.androidauthority.com/windows-10-cortana-bing-only-689963/)

If your search is going through Cortana then Edge, and Bing, are now the only options.

Comment: Thanks. That's really unfortunate though. Microsoft should get their stuff together. Regardless, that clears a lot up for me.

Comment: You're welcome.  And I agree: I want to use Chrome and Google with Cortana.